# What's the best word processing component for .NET

Tags: .net, components, word-processor

I'm looking for a word processing component for .NET that would act like an embedded MS Word in my WinForm/WPF .NET app.  The main goal being for users to be able to create rich formatted text.  I don't really want to have to write a highly custom RichTextBox component.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you can also consider NOV rich text editor. It looks and feel like a Microsoft office document + is cross platform.

Comment: Try the following .NET Word component http://www.thedownloadplanet.com/reviews/review-word-component-for-net/ which lets you add create, load, and manipulate Word documents right in your .NET applications

Answer (score 9):

We're using the TXTextControl release 14 for .Net and we're very happy about it. It has all the positive things you can ask: cheap, well supported, up to date with latest Word releases, fast and not really hungry for memory or resources. The included word processor sample is very good code and we converted it in a proper "word control" in about 1 day of work and included it in our solution in another day, so also using it is very simple, also if it has a lot of features.
Download it from http://www.textcontrol.com/

Answer (score 5):

We have used another Aspose words control to generate word documents in asp.net application and it rendered them perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I've only used the ActiveX version of [TX Text Control](http://www.textcontrol.com/products/client_side/dotnet/features/), but it is very good and I'm sure their .NET version is as well.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously I have no idea what your particular project requirements are, but [ScintillaNET](http://www.codeplex.com/ScintillaNET) is a fabulous control and is flexible enough to do a lot more than just syntax highlighting.  I can foresee cases where it certainly wouldn't be appropriate, but it is at least worth investigating.  After a fair amount of searching it has perfectly filled a void in an application of mine where I need to do extensive contextual highlighting of prose.

**Edit**

I'm revoking this comment because I've thought about it a minute longer and the finite number of styles that Scintilla provides would make it inappropriate for rich text editing.  However, it is still an excellent solution for any situation where you can determine programmatically how styling will be applied.

Answer (score 2):

I use TE Edit control from Subsystems in my app. http://www.subsystems.com/tewf.htm.

Works as expected. I did look at TXTextControl around the time I was evaluating. I think it might have been cost that put me off.

Comment: TE Edit is NOT in the "Best for .Net" category.  It is a very old control written in C++ with a thin .Net wrapper.  The api is still very Win32 procedural in style.  It works, but if you are looking for a native .Net feel, look elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using TinyMCE for about a year now and I love it as a developer and the end users love it, too. It was simple to implement and it's easy to configure which controls the user sees, e.g. the Insert Table button or Paste as Plain Text button.

It's also LGPL license, so for our uses at least, we had no costs to worry about.

https://www.tiny.cloud/

Answer (score 2):

I am the Product Manager of TX Text Control. We listened to requests like this. We have powerful rich text controls for .NET, but you are right: Sometimes, they might be too expensive - even if you don't use all the functionality.

Therefore, we released a free version of TX Text Control - free as in beer.

http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/sites/tx-text-control-express/

Answer (score 0):

if you use WPF, you can check on http://www.wpftexteditor.com

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is this topic still active but I have just the same problem now. I am creating a quotation system in .net winforms and ath the end I have to generate the quote, with product items and some text in .doc. I have scanned the whole net including componentsource and I have found this:
- txControl.. knows everything I need but 900$ (it has cheaper edition as well but that do not export to doc
- aspose.. it is more for asp

i have found also the DSOFramer from Microsoft which is an activeX host for Ms Word. Hm free and gives everything.. of course because it is some kind of word automation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the project lead of Aspose.Words.

My personal opinion is that if you are building any serious piece of software, especially for business or commercial purposes, you ought to have some budget for tools and $900 is not much for what it does. It costs us to develop after all.

But we accept everyone's situation is different, so don't hesitate to post a price question in the Aspose.Purchase forums, maybe you can get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using Apose Words and Cells since version 1.0. Both components are solid, but support is kind of a pain. Personally, I'm not a fan of having to work with people in a different time zone, especially when the only way to get in touch with them is a message board.