# Is there such thing as embedding an HTML editor in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, ckeditor, html-editor

I was recently asked to do some research on some third party HTML editors to be embedded into our current software (Which is built in VB).

I began doing some research, but no luck.

I don't know much about building HTML editors, but is this something that can easily be done?

From what I've been told, I need something like CKEditor, but not for web use.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, their is but it's actually not html editor, it's called RichTextEditor, found in ToolBox from Visual Studio. You can use it for editing html data, but things like for image, link, you'll need to create you own buttons and ammend the html. Ok, here is [one](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/sites/dotnet-rich-text-editor-control/?gclid=CLnHzK-Qzq8CFUYb6wodw2VKZQ)

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely worth looking at

Comment: very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169728/whats-the-best-word-processing-component-for-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TX Text Control](http://textcontrol.com)

Definitely what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

My quick search:
[Microsoft WinForms HTML Editor](http://windowsclient.net/articles/htmleditor.aspx)

http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22html+editor%22+api&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8